# How to properly find root verb using spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I want to check if a word is the root verb using spaCy. I can easily check if the word is, for instance, the subject, like this:

`if word.dep == spacy.symbols.nsubj`

I would think I could then do this for checking if it's the root verb:

`if word.dep == spacy.symbols.ROOT`

but it fails. I can do it like this:

`if word.dep == 512817` or like this `if word.dep_ == "ROOT"`

but both seem wrong. Is there a way more analogous to the first example?

Comment: Nothing has `word.dep == spacy.symbols.root`.

Comment: There is `spacy.symbols.root`, which has a value close to the other dependency tags (around 400). The value 512817 seems odd, too, so this might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with this comparison:

```
if word.text == word.sent.root.text:
  print(word.text, "is root")
```